# Science fiction webcomic (I think set in space?) where time cops attack the protagonists. Their main tactic is retconned parentage

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, webcomics

I was recently reading something, and suddenly had a page from a webcomic pop into my head. I remember that it was earlier (maybe when the time travelers were more friendly to the protagonists?) that the primary time traveler trick involves going back in time, and being someone's parent, and then confronting them with the fact. I think the first time it was shown, they were getting by a guy at the door, and they invoked a childhood memory with the fatherhood revelation, causing the guard to run off crying. The panel I remember was playing it even more for laughs with the time cops *en masse* all being retroactively parents to the people they were trying to get by with it getting more ridiculous as the scene went on with more and more obscure relatives being invoked. I don't remember why this was their tactic rather than actual weapons, although I have a vague memory of that they felt this was non-violent.

I remember the comic as being black-and-white, cartoony without being sketchy. I'm pretty sure it was at least five years ago that I read it, and I think I read it in the archives then. It might have been off of Keenspace or Keenspot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's *[Starslip](https://starslip.krisstraub.com/)*, formerly *Starslip Crisis*. Per the TV Tropes entry for [Tricked Out Time](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrickedOutTime):

> The Time Police Deep Time take this trope and *run* with it. They can't kill (most) anyone in the past, since that will affect the future, but they can, for example, send one of their female agents back in time to be the first girlfriend of a male guard. Then she tries to get past him, and he can't bring himself to shoot her. They do this to about *half* the crew. One poor bastard got his *father* replaced with a Deep Time agent.
>
> *"I've always been proud of you. Sorry I pretended to be your father for the past thirty years so I could get past this door."*

[image: Strip depicting the aftermath of Deep Time meddling]

Comment: Wow, that's a blast from the past.